# CSS - Foundation title bar aligning items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have made a standard title bar with Zurb foundation v. 6:

```
<div class="header-title-bar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="title-bar">
        <div class="title-bar-left">
          <a data-open="offCanvasLeft" class="menu-icon-left"><button class="menu-icon" type="button" ></button><span class="title-bar-title">Meny</span></a>
          <a data-open="offCanvasTop" class="menu-icon-top"><button class="menu-icon" type="button"></button><span class="title-bar-title">Meny</span></a>

        </div>
        <div class="title-bar-right">
          <span class="title-bar-title"><a href="/"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/sfk-logo.png"></a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem that I have is that on the small screens I want to align item vertically, and I have tried to do so with using flex display:

```
.title-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

That aligns items vertically, but the `title-bar-right` then moves all the way to left. How can I align items vertically and still have the `title-bar-left` and `title-bar-right` position each on their side?

Comment: If you make a working code snippet, with all libraries linked, reproducing the issue, it would be easier to see how to solve

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by setting `justify-content` to `space-between` to tell the browser to evenly distribute the content:

```
.title-bar {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content:space-between;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox child items doesn't support floats so although you got it vertically centered the floats in the child items i.e.  (titlebarleft, titlebarright) that you used actually is now useless.
To get them aligned to the ends you need justify-content : space-between. So the whole space will be divided in such a way that the child elements have equal space between them. Since there are just two items they will stick to the ends. However if there would be a third child it will get in middle of those elements. Hence the name: space between.

```
.title-bar {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content:space-between;
   width:100%; (or any other width you like)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override `title-bar` classes for small devices with `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`

```
.title-bar {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.title-bar-left,
.title-bar-right {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

A better way, if you're using Foundation's [flex-grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flex-grid.html), would be to use `row` and `columns` like in this example :

```
<div class="header-title-bar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="title-bar row align-middle">
        <div class="title-bar-left columns">
          <a data-open="offCanvasLeft" class="menu-icon-left"><button class="menu-icon" type="button" ></button><span class="title-bar-title">Meny</span></a>
          <a data-open="offCanvasTop" class="menu-icon-top"><button class="menu-icon" type="button"></button><span class="title-bar-title">Meny</span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="title-bar-right columns shrink">
          <span class="title-bar-title"><a href="/"><img width="50" height="50" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/sfk-logo.png"></a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And just override row's margin :

```
.title-bar {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```